# Explicit special characters from crawling

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on Storm Crawler 1.13 and elastic search 6.5.2. How to restrict the crawler not to crawl/index the special characters `� � � � � ��� �� � •`

Comment: can you give an example of URL and a better descriptions of the characters?

Comment: Well, When I check my Index thoroughly  I am seeing these characters in documents. I am sharing the [document](https://www.rit.edu/dubai/sites/rit.edu.dubai/files/MS%20Brochure.pdf). I didn't see any special characters in this but after crawling and parsing its giving that  � � between the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to write a ParseFilter like

```
        ParseData pd = parse.get(URL);
        String text = pd.getText();
        // remove chars
        pd.setText(text);
```

This will get called on documents parsed by JSoup or Tika.
Have a look at the parse filters in the repository for examples.