# Issue with whitespaces

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on Storm 1.13 and Elastic Search 6.5.2. Crawler is working fine and I have an issue with the whitespaces **/n** and **/t**. When I check the index there are lot of **/n** and **/t**. How Can I avoid these from crawl.

**Sample:**

```
{
   "_index":"some-index",
   "_type":"doc",
   "_id":"12sfsdf3454r5fdsfdsfdgdf",
   "_score":1.0,
   "_source":{
      "content":"\n \n  \n    Skip to main content\n  \n\n    \n\n    \n        \n\t\t\t\n            \n                \n  \n    \n      \n        \n\n      \n\n      \n        \tDirectories | \n\t Home\n\n\n      \n    \n\n  \n                  \n\n            \n\n            \n\n            \n                \n                    \n                          \n    \n\n      \n  \thome ining Services\n\tContact Us\n\n\n\n  \n\n                    \n\n                    \n\n                \n\n            \n\n            \n\n            \n                \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\tToggle navigation\n                        \n                        \n                        \n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tHours & Locations\n\tMenus\n\tStart an Order\n\tPolicies\n\tFAQs\n\tContact\n\tMy Cart\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n                        \t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\n                    \n\n\t\t\t\n\n\n\t\t\t\n\n        \n\n    \n    \n\n    \n\t\t\n        \n            \n            \n         \n\n        \n            \n\n\n                        \n            \t\t\t\t\t\t            \n                 \n\t\t\\t\tFeedback Form\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\n                                    \n                        \n                        \n                                                                                                                                                                           \n                          \n    \n\n      \n  \n    \n                  \n    This form is for general feedback about your . If you need to request a refund or cancel your order, please contact your order location directly, or consult our Refund and Cancellation policy.\n\n\n\n\n\n Full Name *\n\n\n\n\n\n E-mail Address *\n\n\n\n\n\n Your Message *\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nSubmit\n\n\n\n    \n\n\n  \n\n                        \n                        \n                    \n\n                                                            \n\n            \n                        \n                                                \n\n            \n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\n            \n                \n                    \n\n                        \n                            \n                                \n                                    Contact Us\n                                \n\n                                \n                                    \n                                    \t\n                                        \t\n                                            \t\n                                        \t\n\n                                        \n                                        \n                                            \n                                                Email\n                                            \n\n                                            \n                                                                                            \n\n                                        \n\n                                        \n\n                                    \n\n                                    \n                                        \n                                            \n                                        \n\n                                        \n                                            \n                                                Phone\n                                            \n\n                                            \n                                            n                                            \n\n                                        \n\n                                        \n\n                                    \n\n                                    \n                                    \t\n                                        \t\n                                            \t\n                                        \t\n\n                                        \n                              ",
      "url":"https://someurl.test.edu/feedback-form",
      "domain":"test.edu",
      "title":[
         "Feedback Form | Organize",
         "Feedback Form | Organize"
      ]
   }
},
```

Comment: You asked this question before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096045/explicit-special-characters-from-crawling - the answer is still the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicit special characters from crawling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096045/explicit-special-characters-from-crawling)

Answer (score 0):

Having tabs and new lines has no impact on the search with Elasticsearch but you could of course write a custom ParseFilter to rewrite them into spaces if you wanted to.